# Postman with Django REST and AngularJS

Tags: django, angularjs, postman

I have a Django REST framework API which is accessed with a AngularJS frontend.
If I had a Django App called `models`, I could simply request its data in Postman simply by sending a `GET` to the URL `localhost:8000/models/`.

But since everything is routed through AngularJS and every Django App has multiple Controllers, that doesn't work. The `GET` on `localhost:8000/models/` returns just the `index.html`, the entry point of the AngularJS.

So how can I achieve to send `GET`, `POST` etc. to the API?

BTW: I managed to get an `X-CSRFToken` by sending `POST` to `http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/` with login and password keys ans values. That URL was included in the Django Projects `urls.py` as `urlpatterns`.
No such urlpattern for the App `models`, or any other Django App, though.

Comment: I would suggest using a reverse proxy. You could have nginx in front of Django and route the path `/api` for example to Django and everything else be handled by Angular. The front end should be just some static HTML and JS that then generates pages from API on the client side, so it can be served directly by nginx.

Comment: @MichalKrejčí --- I'll have to read and learn about nginx first. also: this "nginx" should only be used in Postman testing right? because i'm working on an existing WebAPI that I have to update.

Comment: no, I thought that would be used in production. Could you try to add more deails regarding development and deployment environments? Things like OS, web server, URLs, if known, etc. Then I can maybe help more

Comment: it runs on an ApacheServer within a python env. DB for one is 10.3.25 MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04, for the other its 5.7.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL). but i'm not going to change production code. i just want to be able to test with postman.

Comment: Apache is fine too, nginx is just a tad easier, thats all. Who serves the Angular pages? Django or Apache?

Comment: i think Django is oblivious to AngularJS. but the AngularJS code with html files are in an `app` directory in `BASE_DIR`, referenced in `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS.`